# Is it possible to use a GSuite group mail id as an alias to send mails using Gmail API?

Tags: google-api, google-compute-engine, gmail-api, google-workspace

My use case is to send mails from a GCP Compute Instance through its default service account with the sender as my GSuite group email which I have created for our business domain.

Could you please let me know if it is really possible to use that GSuite group email as a sender?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In order to use an email as an alias, you have to set it up first in the UI, see [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en).

Comment: @ziganotschka as that will be an alias but can't I authenticate with that email? can't I avoid my account completely?